Applicability of the current of the polarization charge
The polarization current is given by $J_p=\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}$. There can be another current in ferroelectrics expressed by the polarization charge multiplied by the velocity of electrons (denoted as $v_{e^{-}}$):
$$ J'_p=(−\nabla⋅P) v_{e^{-}}$$
Is it meaningful to consider $J'_p=(−\nabla⋅P) v_{e^{-}}$? Does anybody know any examples?
